# Reporting limitations and automated emails

Tags: ms-access, conditional-statements, ms-access-reports

I have a report set up with conditional formatting where items are highlighted if they fall below a predetermined threshold. If I set up a scheduled task to run the query/reports each morning, is it possible to automate an email ONLY if there are items under the thresholds? Would this require a scheduled task a set of If/Then statements with the parameters? Or is Access not capable of this? What I have read so far is that Access is not the best reporting tool and is limited, and a secondary program *may* be needed; has anyone done this successfully within access and Windows Task Scheduler?

Here is what I have so far:

```
 Private Sub Command3_Click()
 On Error GoTo Command3_Click_Err
    Me.Requery "AverageInventoryPreparation", , acReadOnly
    If [AverageInventoryPreparation].[Store Response] < 6 Then
    DoCmd.SendObject  acReport, "All_Stores_InventorySurveys_Summary", "PDFFormat(*.pdf)", "ShaneFitzpatrick@segrocers.com", "", "", "Stores Outside Parameters", "Please see the attached PDF that has been identified with exceptions.", True, ""
```

Command3_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Command3_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Command3_Click_Exit

End Sub

Comment: This is certainly possible. With which part exactly are you having difficulty?

Comment: Thank you, Erik - I value your assistance. 1.) Is Windows Task Scheduler the only way (without additional cost by purchasing outside software) to: open database which will run a LoadEvent to grab data (on a shared drive) from the previous day in order to update report (called Store Summary), and apply conditional statements (for example) IF [Store Response]<4.5 Then DoCmd.SendObject acReport, "Store Summary" etc. ?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. There are lots of ways to execute a time-based command in Windows (I've used Karen's countdown timer in the past for some specific things). You can make a link to execute a macro, you can execute VBA through a macro, and you can do anything with VBA.

Comment: OK, I will check out Karen's countdown timer and figure out the execution. Still having trouble with how to send report only if values are below ...Is this not logical:  Me.Requery "Store Summary" .... IF [Store Response]<4.5 Then ....DoCmd.SendObject. acReport, "All_Store_Summary" ....?

Comment: With "Store Summary" being the query behind the report "All_Store_Summary"

Comment: I can't answer such half questions with unformatted code, sorry. It might be completely logical, or utter nonsense, depending on the exact situation. There's little advantage using Karens Countdown Timer over Windows Task Scheduler, I mainly used it for the easy UI, but it's a fine application.

Comment: well thanks for mentioning Karen, have a nice day.

Comment: Can you post the code that you have so far? I think I see the problem, but I don't want to spend the time on the answer without more context.

Comment: Hi Christopher - I have added it above.